# Transition of two views

Tags: xcode, view, transition

**I want to know how i can do transition os two views, and then stop and entenr the menu....and how to change the views in a animated way, can anyone help me?
thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

The [Animations section of the *View Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) tells you all you need to know about animating views and includes plenty of sample code.